# Git alias for simpler checkout from github and bitbucket.org

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

I have been checking out a lot of repositories lately and I want to make one alias for my commonly used sites, to make the initial checkout easier. I wanted something like:

```
git clonegithub opencv/opencv
git clonebitbucket
```

I started with the following aliases but they ended up cloning to my home directory:

```
[alias]
clonegithub = "!git clone git@github.com:$1.git"
clonebitbucket = "!git clone git@bitbucket.org:$1.git"
clonemyorg = "!cd \"${GIT_PREFIX:-.}\" && git clone git@bitbucket.org:MyOrg/$1.git #"
```

Comment: For github, perhaps you would be happy to use: https://hub.github.com/

Comment: That looks great. I will have to check this out soon :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
git config --global url.git@github.com:.insteadOf gh:
git config --global url.git@bitbucket.org:.insteadOf bb:
```

Now run

```
git clone gh:sqlobject/sqlobject.git
```

See https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-urlltbasegtinsteadOf

Comment: I had a feeling there might me a way to do something like this with global configuration. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out at git aliased commands are typically run in the root of the current repo. Since the .gitconfig is in ~ and the "git clone" command is repo-less this trys to run git clone in ~.

To fix this use GIT_PREFIX to find the directory the command was run from and cd there. Here are the aliases that I ended up with:

```
[alias]
clonebb = "!cd \"${GIT_PREFIX:-.}\" && git clone git@bitbucket.org:$1/$1.git #"
clonegh = "!cd \"${GIT_PREFIX:-.}\" && git clone git@github.com:$1/$1.git #"
```